# Time varying voltages

Tags: voltage, current, ac, dc

Hi I am in an introductory circuit analysis course and we just got to the portion over time varying voltages and currents through inductors and capacitors. We aren’t on the alternating current section yet but I don’t understand how these time varying voltages can be considered DC seeing as how the voltages and currents aren’t constant. Can anyone explain this to me?

Comment: They're not DC. Who said they were?

Comment: Patrick, you need to provide the circuit in question. It's possible that you are discussing a simple diode circuit (say two diodes and two caps?) If so, then the explanation isn't difficult. But you need to let us know what you are looking at -- the details are important.

Answer (score 3):

They're not DC.

Distinguish time-varying voltages and currents vs. steady-state response to sinusoidal excitation.

The latter is much more restrictive (less general) than the former, but using AC analysis techniques allows vast simplification in many cases.

It may be difficult or impossible to find closed-form solutions in relatively simple situations of transient analysis because you have to find solutions to a differential equation, which is not necessarily straightforward.  Of course in modern times we often use numerical solvers (such as the SPICE engine) which can give us very useful answers in transient and nonlinear situations.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are confusing the voltages *applied* to the capacitor (that, at least on the first approach are usually constant, so DC) with the voltage resulting for the charges *on the plates* (this varies: an exponential curve when charging from a DC voltage thru a resistor).

The difference is took by the charging resistor, in the elementary DC charge circuit. If there is no charging resistor (as in a capacitor directly attached to a power supply), there is *anyway* a resistor: the copper wiring from the supply to the capacitor has a finite resistance (usually in the order of milliohms).

So you apply a DC (constant) voltage to an empty capacitor and observe an exponential (varying) voltage on the plates.